# Why does the browser render a different background color from CSS?

Tags: css, web, colors

I have a div with `background-color: rgb(231, 224, 216)`, but my browser renders it as `rgb(224, 217, 208)`. See below picture:

[image]

It's not browser dependent. I tried Safari/Chrome/Firefox and they all render the same result. So I guess there is a CSS trick I don't know. How to prevent browser from adjusting my color? (It's not due to the shadow from DigitalColor Meter window. I moved it closer just to take screenshot.)

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this issue is caused by browser or css especially if, like you wrote, all browsers render the same color of the background. I'd guess that the color picker you use gets a color that is rendered on your monitor, given all the modifiers like selected luminosity and saturation.